# When to use Box instead of reference?

Tags: pointers, rust

I'm new to Rust and I'm trying to understand when a `Box` should be used instead of a regular reference.

All the examples I can find show how to use a `Box`, but none of them explain in what situation you should use them over regular `&` references.

Comment: See also [When Should I Use Box<T> - help - The Rust Programming Language Forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/when-should-i-use-box-t/4411).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

(*Additional to Shepmaster's great answer: another way to think of ownership*)

**➡** You always have to think about: where does the value **live**?

For example, data can live on the stack, in some special place of the executable, or in a `Box`. On the other hand, a reference isn't a place to **live** in -- it just points to some data that **lives** *somewhere else*. So:

- if you know that the data you want to work with has a home to live in: you can usually just use a reference (address) to just get access to it (visit it ✈).
- if your data does not have a place to live in, put it in a box to give it a home  ♥

---

The chapters [ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html) and [borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/references-and-borrowing.html) in the Rust book are a great way to learn about these concepts.

Answer (score 16):

A `Box` denotes that a type is **owned** and that it is allocated **on the heap**. A reference (`&`) denotes that you are **borrowing** the value from something else.

You can even get a reference from a `Box` (explicit types are not needed here, only shown for clarity):

```
let boxed: Box<i32> = Box::new(42);
let reference: &i32 = &boxed;
```

The primary distinction boils down to *ownership*. When you own a value, you can do more things to it, such as destroying it or controlling its mutability.

Heap vs stack is also important, but less immediately so. Stacks tend to have a fixed size that is relatively small (on my machine it's 8MiB), so declaring large variables on the stack can lead to exhausting that memory. The heap tends to be bigger, conceptually addressing 2^32 or 2^48 bytes.

[*The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) has a [section on ownership](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ownership.html) as well as a section on [the stack and the heap](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/the-stack-and-the-heap.html); I'd encourage you to read both.